# Python : Help for an elegant list comprehension for an awkward format

Tags: python, machine-learning, list-comprehension

I currently have data file of sparse matrix data that looks like the following

```
i j value

0 0 1
5 1 7
1 101 9

...
```

And was able to read this data as a list of (i, j, value) tuples with the following comprehension.

```py
with open("sparse-data.data", "r") as f :
    lines = f.readlines()
    sparse_format = [tuple(int(x) for x in line.split(" ")]) for line in lines]
```

The goal here is that I need to reconstruct the actual matrix from this given format.

I have attempted the following

```py
X = [[]]
for data_point in sparse_format : 
    for i, j, val in data_point :
        X[i][j] = val
```

But no success. Any tips? Thanks in advance!

~ Matt

Comment: Find the largest i and j and initialize `X` to proper size accordingly?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to do?

Comment: Depending on what libraries you're using, you may find [`scipy.sparse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pandas` which is able to output a dataframe (your imported data file) as a `numpy` array.

According to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import pandas as pd

# define sample data for pandas DataFrame
d = {'i': [0, 5, 1], 'j': [0, 1, 101], 'val': [1, 7, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# print DataFrame to double check format
print(df)

# df.values gives DataFrame as Numpy array
print(df.values)
```

Output:

```
   i    j  val
0  0    0    1
1  5    1    7
2  1  101    9

[[  0   0   1]
 [  5   1   7]
 [  1 101   9]]
```

To import your data from a file I would suggest using `pandas.read_csv()` which is described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table) and gives:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sparse-data.data', sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is a sparse matrix, you may consider using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) indexed by tuples:

```
from collections import defaultdict

X = defaultdict(int)
for data_point in sparse_format : 
    for i, j, val in data_point :
       X[i,j] = val
```

Only the values from the file are actually stored in the dictionary. With a `defaultdict(int)`, if you try to access a key that is not actually in the dictionary, you will just get zero.

If you really want to store all of the zeros in a giant list of lists, you can initialize `X` as:

```
X = [[0 for i in xrange(MAX_INDEX)] for j in xrange(MAX_INDEX)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using map function

```
def get_matrix(mat):
    return map(lambda x:list(x), mat)
```